# Why do System.err statements get printed first sometimes?

Tags: java, stdout, stderr

In Java, I noticed that sometimes, `System.err` statements get printed first before `System.out` statements, although the latter appears first before the former in my code. Why? I'm curious.

Comment: From 1.02 I've stuck with using `System.err` when I'm hacking about for exactly this reason. No idea how more recent versions of Java behave, because I don't test it out.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Typically, `System.out` is a buffered output stream, so text is accumulated before it is flushed to the destination location.  This can dramatically improve performance in applications that print large amounts of text, since it minimizes the number of expensive system calls that have to be made.  However, it means that text is not always displayed immediately, and may be printed out much later than it was written.

`System.err`, on the other hand, typically is not buffered because error messages need to get printed immediately.  This is slower, but the intuition is that error messages may be time-critical and so the program slowdown may be justified.  According to [the Javadoc for `System.err`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#err):

> Typically this stream corresponds to display output or another output destination specified by the host environment or user. **By convention, this output stream is used to display error messages or other information that should come to the immediate attention of a user** even if the principal output stream, the value of the variable out, has been redirected to a file or other destination that is typically not continuously monitored.

(My emphasis)

However, as a result, old data sent to `System.out` might show up after newer `System.err` messages, since the old buffered data is flushed later than the message was sent to `System.err`.  For example this sequence of events:

- "Hello," is buffered to `System.out`
- "PANIC" is sent directly to `System.err` and is printed immediately.
- " world!" is buffered to `System.out`, and the buffered data is printed

Would result in the output

```
PANIC
Hello, world!
```

Even though `Hello` was printed to `System.out` before `PANIC` was printed to `System.err`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Does java make the same guarantees as C wrt stdout when piped to a terminal? I.e. we flush the buffer every time a newline is written?

Comment: @Voo- I just looked at the Javadoc and there doesn't appear to be anything of this sort.

Comment: `PrintStream` is implemented to flush after just about everything (I think you can directly `write` and it doesn't).

Answer (score 2):

It has to do with buffering and priority. Presumably, Java (like C and C-derivatives) does not buffer `System.err`, `stderr`, etc., unlike `System.out`, `stdout`, etc. This way, the system can ensure that you'll most likely get any relevant error messages, even if it has to drop standard output for one reason or other.

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_error_.28stderr.29):

> It is acceptable—and normal—for standard output and standard error to be directed to the same destination, such as the text terminal. Messages appear in the same order as the program writes them, unless buffering is involved. (For example, a common situation is when the standard error stream is unbuffered but the standard output stream is line-buffered; in this case, text written to standard error later may appear on the terminal earlier, if the standard output stream's buffer is not yet full.)

Comment: I've never heart of any priorities for streams.. how'd that work? I'd go with the simple buffering explanation.

Comment: Just a flowery-language problem. Fixed to be more technical :)