# Race-condition in linear java-program

Tags: java, race-condition

the attached programcode produces the following output most of the time:

```
6.0
8.0
10.0
12.0

java.lang.RuntimeException: dimensions not matching
    at hausaufgaben.linearAlgebra1.VectorRn.add(VectorRn.java:41)
    at hausaufgaben.linearAlgebra1.VectorRn.main(VectorRn.java:19)

3.0
6.0
9.0
12.0
```

but at the second execution it produced following output

```
6.0
8.0
10.0
12.0

java.lang.RuntimeException: dimensions not matching
3.0
6.0
9.0
12.0

    at hausaufgaben.linearAlgebra1.VectorRn.add(VectorRn.java:41)
    at hausaufgaben.linearAlgebra1.VectorRn.main(VectorRn.java:19)
```

does this mean that in simple programms with consoleoutput there are already race-conditions that behave deterministically in 99.99% of the time ?

or is the catch statement executed in a seperate thread ?

or is the console.output cued up ina weird way ?

I'm confused at how something like this could have occured, even if it is rare.

```
package hausaufgaben.linearAlgebra1;

public class VectorRn {
/**
 * values that are the components
 */
private double[] values;

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    VectorRn a = new VectorRn(1,2,3,4);
    VectorRn b = new VectorRn(5,6,7,8);
    VectorRn c = new VectorRn(1,2);
    double d = 3;
    System.out.println(a.add(b).toString());
    try {
        System.out.println(a.add(c).toString());
    }catch(Exception e) {
        e.getMessage();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("\n"+a.mult(d).toString());
}    

/**
 * @param values copies the values passed to the constructor
 */
public VectorRn(double... values) {
    this.values = new double[values.length];
    System.arraycopy(values, 0, this.values, 0, values.length);
}

/**
 * @param v2 the vector added to a clone of this object
 * @return the sum of this Vector and v2
 */
public VectorRn add(VectorRn v2) {
    if(this.values.length != v2.values.length)
        throw new RuntimeException("dimensions not matching");
    VectorRn modifiedClone = new VectorRn(this.values);
    for(int i = 0; i < modifiedClone.values.length; i++){
        modifiedClone.values[i] += v2.values[i];
    }
    return modifiedClone;
}


/**
 * @param d the scalar by which the clone of this object will be multiplied
 * @return the d'th multiple of this Vector
 */
public VectorRn mult(double d) {
    VectorRn modifiedClone = new VectorRn(this.values);
    for(int i = 0; i < this.values.length; i++) {
        modifiedClone.values[i] *= d;
    }
    return modifiedClone;
}

/**
 * @return a string that contains a list of the components of the vector separated by newline characters
 * @see java.lang.Object#toString()
 */
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder tmp = new StringBuilder();
    for(double d : values) {
        tmp.append(d);
        tmp.append("\n");
    }
    return tmp.toString();
}
}
```

Answer (score 5):

[`e.printStackTrace`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#printStackTrace%28%29) prints messages to stderr (`System.err`), whereas all other output goes to stdout (`System.out`). By default, both [standard output streams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams) are redirected onto the same target (your terminal). So your program is running deterministically, it's just outputting to two to channels.

This behavior is actually a good idea; a program can redirect the output but still present errors to the users. If you however don't want it, you can print errors to stdout with

```
e.printStackTrace(System.out)
```

Comment: +1. Note that this does, in fact, reflect concurrency: at some level in the terminal, the writing of standard output and the writing of standard error are happening in parallel.

Comment: thanks for the answer, makes sense but I would never have guessed that the statments are printed non-atomic, as the stacktrace is divided into 2 parts here, on the other hand I have no clue what exactly happens when printing

Answer (score 1):

There is only one thread so there can't be a race condition in your code. What you are seeing is the interleaving of `System.out` and `System.err` streams. See for example [Cause runtime exceptions to be properly ordered with println in console output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17114769/cause-runtime-exceptions-to-be-properly-ordered-with-println-in-console-output)