# Does throwing exception involves a new different thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, exception, enums

I am trying to learn enum in java, i wrote a code to understand the use of valueOf & values, i understood my mistake as the valueOf is case sensitive, so exception was thrown.

But i was surprised to see that output was not in order as i expected, as per my understanding this can only happen when more than one thread is involved, Bur here only one main thread is running.
here is my program:

```
public enum Currency {
PENNY(1) {
        @Override
        public String color() {
            return "bronze";
        }
    }, 



    NICKLE(5) {
        @Override
        public String color() {
            return "bronze";
        }
    }, DIME(10) {
        @Override
        public String color() {
            return "silver";
        }
    }, QUARTER(25) {
        @Override
        public String color() {
            return "silver";
        }
    };
    private int value;

    public abstract String color();

    private Currency(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }  


    public static void main(String[] args) {


        for(Currency i: Currency.values()){
            System.out.println(i.toString());

        }

        System.out.println(Currency.valueOf("penny"));

    }
}
```

and this is the output i got:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum const class learn.enumeration.Currency.penny
    at java.lang.Enum.valueOf(Unknown Source)
    at learn.enumeration.Currency.valueOf(Currency.java:1)
    at learn.enumeration.Currency.main(Currency.java:54)
PENNY
NICKLE
DIME
QUARTER
```

According to me first for-each loop should be executed and then this exception should appear.When i tried it executing again, i get this result also... it gave me hint of two thread involvement in this scenario... But where did i create the another thread?? 
Thanks in Advance

Comment: I ran this code multiple times and always got expected result, i.e. list of coins and the exception. What platform/JVM you're running this on? PS. overriding `color` for every enum value is quite redundant here, why don't you just pass the color as an argument of constructor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's only one thread involved. You see the exception before the rest of the output because the exception is output into standard error stream (stderr, `System.err`), not standard output stream (stdout, `System.out`).

Standard output stream is usually buffered, so it may not output what you push into it immediately, while standard error stream is usually **not** buffered. For more information on this topic, see [Why do System.err statements get printed first sometimes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9146257/759064).